# Adding another "Add Post" button to admin

Tags: admin, css, buttons

I would like another "Add post" button in the admin except I am going to call it "Add voucher". It will run specific plugins that add post will not. However that is irrelivant, all I need to know it how to add another add post button with the same features.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately this isn't possible (without a slight hack)- since there are no hooks provided (see for example the [`edit.php` page](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4/wp-admin/edit.php)).

A quick and easy hack is to use JavaScript to add the link after the usual 'Add New' link. Here I've used the `admin_print_footer_scripts` hook (on 'post', or 'edit-post' screens) to print the JavaScript. Note that you must alter this to work for other post types.

```
add_action('admin_print_footer_scripts','wpse57033_add_new_voucher_link');
function wpse57033_add_new_voucher_link(){
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if( $screen->id == 'edit-post' || $screen->id == 'post' ){
        ?>
            <script>
            jQuery('.wrap h2 .add-new-h2').after('<a href="" class="add-new-h2">Add New Voucher</a>');
            </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: @RuturaajPatki asked why some people check `$variable == 'value'` and others `'value'== $variable`. I've been lazy in this answer, but the latter is **best practise** ([see this for an explanation](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards#Yoda_Conditions)). Otherwise they are the same.

Comment: `$screen` is an object, when making comparisons, it can help to force `(string)` type in the evaluation.

Example Code:
`if( ( (string)$screen->id == 'user-edit' || (string)$screen->id == 'users' ) && ( current_user_can('editor') || current_user_can('administrator') ) ){ // do stuff }
`

Screen Type Reference:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Admin_Screen_Reference